# Вычислить из CSV одни данные по сравнению с другими

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Всем привет. Снова у меня вопрос по Pandas. Имеются данные в CSV. По задаче есть 3 признака **salary** - это заработок далее пол **sex** и семейное положение **marital-status** . Мне необходимо посчитать среди кого больше тех кто зарабатывает >50K среди женатых или холостых мужчин. Те кто женатые в признаке marital-staus имеют следующие значения: *Married-civ-spouse, Married-spouse-absent или Married-AF-spouse* . Следовательно остальные значения в признаке **marital-staus** означают что холост.
Для удобства я выведу только те признаки из таблицы с которыми нужно работать:

```
df = pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv', usecols=['sex', 'salary', 'marital-status'])
```

[image: Признаки и их значения]

Далее я могу увидеть сколько мужчин зарабатывающих более 50К имеющих нужные мне семейные положения наблюдаются в данных

```
df[(df['sex'] == 'Male') & (df['salary'] == '>50K')]['marital-status'].value_counts().loc[['Married-civ-spouse', 'Married-spouse-absent', 'Married-AF-spouse']]
```

Также можно по каждому отдельно взятому значению семейному положению получить необходимый результат

```
df = df[(df['sex'] == 'Male') & (df['salary'] == '>50K')]['marital-status'].value_counts().loc['Never-married']
```

Таким образом я могу получить кол во мужчин зарабатывающих >50K и имеющих определённое семейное положение. Далее получить кол во уже с другими семейными положениями и посчитать кого из них больше. Но думаю так как я хочу решить , это не правильно. 100% есть более адекватный метод. Подскажите как лучше сделать, уверен что можно одной строчкой.
Ссылка на файл csv https://yadi.sk/d/qG6JiaqlWgBV5A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['sex', 'salary', 'marital-status'])

married = ['Married-civ-spouse', 'Married-spouse-absent', 'Married-AF-spouse']

res = (df.assign(married=np.where(df["marital-status"].isin(married), 'married', 'not married'))
         .loc[(df['salary']=='>50K') & (df['sex']=='Male')]
         .groupby('married')
         .size()
         .idxmax())

print(res)
```

Вывод на экран:

```
married
```

Пошагово:

```
In [61]: (df.assign(married=np.where(df["marital-status"].isin(married), 'married', 'not married')))
Out[61]:
              marital-status     sex salary      married
0              Never-married    Male  <=50K  not married
1         Married-civ-spouse    Male  <=50K      married
2                   Divorced    Male  <=50K  not married
3         Married-civ-spouse    Male  <=50K      married
4         Married-civ-spouse  Female  <=50K      married
5         Married-civ-spouse  Female  <=50K      married
6      Married-spouse-absent  Female  <=50K      married
7         Married-civ-spouse    Male   >50K      married
8              Never-married  Female   >50K  not married
9         Married-civ-spouse    Male   >50K      married
...                      ...     ...    ...          ...
32551     Married-civ-spouse    Male  <=50K      married
32552     Married-civ-spouse    Male  <=50K      married
32553          Never-married    Male  <=50K  not married
32554     Married-civ-spouse    Male   >50K      married
32555          Never-married    Male  <=50K  not married
32556     Married-civ-spouse  Female  <=50K      married
32557     Married-civ-spouse    Male   >50K      married
32558                Widowed  Female  <=50K  not married
32559          Never-married    Male  <=50K  not married
32560     Married-civ-spouse  Female   >50K      married

[32561 rows x 4 columns]

In [62]: (df.assign(married=np.where(df["marital-status"].isin(married), 'married', 'not married'))
    ...:    .loc[(df['salary']=='>50K') & (df['sex']=='Male')])
Out[62]:
           marital-status   sex salary  married
7      Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
9      Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
10     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
11     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
14     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
20     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
25     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
27     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
38     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
45     Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
...                   ...   ...    ...      ...
32480  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32506  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32510  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32518  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32519  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32532  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32533  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32539  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32554  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married
32557  Married-civ-spouse  Male   >50K  married

[6662 rows x 4 columns]

In [64]: (df.assign(married=np.where(df["marital-status"].isin(married), 'married', 'not married'))
    ...:    .loc[(df['salary']=='>50K') & (df['sex']=='Male')]
    ...:    .groupby('married')
    ...:    .size())
Out[64]:
married
married        5965
not married     697
dtype: int64
```

Comment: А что такое у вас married ? У меня ошибка выходит именно на нём name 'married' is not defined

Comment: @IT-KOT, пардон, забыл указать в ответе... Сейчас  дополнил ответ

Comment: По двум вариантам он мне вот такой трейс выбрасывает :NameError: name 'married' is not defined

Comment: @IT-KOT, вы пробовали сделать `copy & paste` - скопировать команды из ответа и запутисть их? ;)

Comment: Так сейчас работает выдал True при запуске первого кода

Comment: Правда я не совсем понимаю что это) правильно у меня всё работает)

Comment: Или в переменную married  необходимо передать значения признака  marital-staus ?

Comment: @IT-KOT, добавил пошаговое пояснение - надеюсь это поможет разобраться с тем как работает решение

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Запущу уже завтра) Без сомнений ваш ответ полезен!